# Maintaining focus on input box when virtual keypad icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an input box with an icon inside of it which, when clicked, brings out a virtual keypad for accented letters. The code works perfect except that whenever the icon (or any button on the virtual keypad) is clicked, the input box loses focus. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <input id="word" type="textbox" placeholder="Enter your word here..." class="form-control input-lg lookup-field lookup-field-single" onMouseOver="$(this).focus();" required>
          <span class="fa fa-keyboard-o fa-2x kb-icon" onclick="toggler('virtualkeypad', this);"></span>
          <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary lookup-submit" type="button" id="lookup"  onclick="lookup()">Lookup</button></span>
        </div>

        <div id="virtualkeypad" class="btn-group keypad-hidden col-md-offset-4">
          <button class="btn btn-lg first-btn" type="button" onClick="spl_character('á');">á</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('é');">é</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('í');">í</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ó');">ó</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ú');">ú</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ü');">ü</button>
          <button class="btn btn-lg last-btn" type="button" onClick="spl_character('ñ');">ñ</button>
        </div>
```

I tried adding the code to regain focus (`document.getElementById("word").focus();`) in JS like so:

```
toggler = function (eid, eclass) {
  document.getElementById("word").focus();
  $("#" + eid).toggleClass('keypad-hidden');
  $(eclass).toggleClass('keypad-shown');
}
```

This does bring back the focus upon click; however, there still remains a short burst of lost focus during the time the mouse button remains pressed. In order to remedy this, I used an `onmousedown` event against the `kb-icon` div in the HTML file, still no luck. I even tried something like this:

```
$('.kb-icon').addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
 document.getElementById("word").focus();
});
```

And even that failed to work. In order to illustrate the problem better, the input box in question (#word) is set to a yellow background when inactive and white when in use. Now say you're ready to type in something and the cursor is inside the input box. The box will be white since it's active. This is how it should remain even when you click the virtual keypad icon. However, what's happening is the box turns yellow (as it would when out of focus) when you point the mouse at the virtual keypad icon and then goes back to being white (in focus) the moment the mouse is released. Any idea what might be going wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the parameter class in the function toggler is a reserved identifier. Also its not advisable to use same id for different elements, in your case "id=key" is repeated for the buttons..

See the below updated code which will set the focus to the input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
toggler = function (id, elclass) {
  document.getElementById("word").focus();
  $("#" + id).toggleClass('keypad-hidden');
  $(elclass).toggleClass('keypad-shown');
}
</script>
```

Comment: This does nothing to address the issue at hand. Thanks for suggesting corrections to the code at large but my concern here is maintaining the focus on the input box (`lookup-field`) element during the `mousedown` event on `kb-icon`.

Comment: Like I said in the question, "there still remains a short burst of lost focus during the time the mouse button remains pressed." The same happens in your fiddle as well. The inputbox remains out of focus during the entire duration of mousedown on the keyboard icon. The focus returns only when the mouse button is released.

Comment: @sandeeps: Thanks for the fiddle. The problem persists. In order to see what I'm talking about, just click on the keyboard icon and continue to hold without releasing the mouse. You'll notice that for the entire duration of `mousedown`, the focus stays away from the input box. This is what I want to prevent. I need the focus to stay on the box even during that `mousedown` event. Same goes with the keys on the virtual keypad as well. The focus should not leave the input box when the individual special character keys are in a `mousedown` event.

Comment: i don't think a user is going to hold the keypress or mousedown event for a long time. i feel like you want to move a car forward by applying clutch and brake together.